# How can I use vb.net to display the output I want while simultaneously utilising many filters in the winform?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

| week | year | product | sampling | x1 | x2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 2023 | TBB12 | Resample | 0.11 | 0.03 |
| 5 | 2023 | TAA12 | Resample | 0.07 | 0.05 |
| 3 | 2023 | TCC23 | Normal | 0.04 | 0.07 |
| 3 | 2023 | TCC25 | Normal | 0.02 | 0.08 |
| 3 | 2023 | TAA13 | Normal | 0.01 | 0.04 |
| 2 | 2023 | TBB12 | Normal | 0.06 | 0.02 |
| 2 | 2023 | TCC24 | Normal | 0.07 | 0.09 |
| 2 | 2023 | TBB13 | Resample | 0.09 | 0.05 |
| 1 | 2023 | TAA12 | Resample | 0.04 | 0.02 |
| 1 | 2023 | TAA13 | Normal | 0.02 | 0.05 |
| 1 | 2023 | TBB13 | Normal | 0.06 | 0.06 |
| 1 | 2023 | TAA13 | Normal | 0.04 | 0.04 |

An example of a dataset can be found at the top of the table; in this case, I want to filter the product as TAA12 and the sampling as Resample. However, regardless of which filter you use, the code in the comboBox2 and comboBox3 will always reset the dataTable. I am a complete newbie, and I have no idea how to programme the filtering on comboBox2 before continuing to comboBox3 or filtering on comboBox3 before continuing to comboBox2 without resetting the dataTable, and then displaying the results in datagridview1.

This is my code:

```
    Private Sub LoadData()
            Dim query1 As String = "SELECT DISTINCT productFROM ppiDB;"
            Dim query2 As String = "SELECT DISTINCT sampling FROM ppiDB;"
    
    
            Try
                'Load product types
                Using conn1 As New MySqlConnection(sqlServer)
                    conn1.Open()
                    Using cmd1 As New MySqlCommand(query1, conn1)
                        Using reader1 As MySqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
                            While reader1.Read()
                                ComboBox2.Items.Add(reader1("product").ToString())
                            End While
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
    
                'Load sampling
                Using conn2 As New MySqlConnection(sqlServer)
                    conn2.Open()
                    Using cmd2 As New MySqlCommand(query2, conn2)
                        Using reader2 As MySqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
                            While reader2.Read()
                                ComboBox3.Items.Add(reader2("sampling").ToString())
                            End While
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
    
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error loading data: " & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Sub
    
    
        Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
            conn = New MySqlConnection(sqlServer)
            Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM testingDB.ppiDB WHERE product LIKE @product"
            Try
                Dim searchTerm As String = ""
                Dim searchTermQuery As String = ""
    
                If ComboBox2.Text = "TAA12" Then
                    searchTerm = "%AA%"
                ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "TAA13" Then
                    searchTerm = "%AA%"
                ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "TBB12" Then
                    searchTerm = "%BB%"
                ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "TBB13" Then
                    searchTerm = "%BB%"
                ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "TCC23" Then
                    searchTerm = "%CC%"
                ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "TCC24" Then
                    searchTerm = "%CC%"
                ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "TCC25" Then
                    searchTerm = "%CC%"
                End If
    
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(searchTerm, conn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product", searchTerm)
    
                Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim ds As New DataSet()
    
                adapter.Fill(ds)
    
                Dim dataTable As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable
            Catch ex As Exception
                InsertLog("Product Filtering" & ex.ToString, "Error From ComboBox2")
            End Try
        End Sub
    
        Private Sub ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged
            conn = New MySqlConnection(sqlServer)
            Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM testingDB.ppiDB WHERE sampling LIKE @sampling"
    
            Try
    
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sampling", ComboBox3.Text)
    
                Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim ds As New DataSet()
    
                adapter.Fill(ds)
    
                Dim dataTable As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable
    
            Catch ex As Exception
                InsertLog("Sampling Filtering" & ex.ToString, "Error From ComboBox3")
            End Try
    
        End Sub
```

My expected output is in the picture:
[image]

Comment: I thought that I'd already answered this question. Did you delete it and repost? I believe that you claimed to have tried what I suggested and it didn't work but I see no sign of that here, so it appears that you just ignored my advice.

Comment: Well it's seems to be doing exactly what you're telling it to do.  In Both the SelectedIndexChanged event handlers you re-querying the DB with no regard for the previously selected filter.  You can either restructure your query(s) so that it respects BOTH filters or restructure your app to query a filtered in memory collection